# Characteristic Functions in Quantum Optics for linear amplifiers/attenuators

Tags: quantum-optics

I am following along with the MIT OCW quantum optical communication course. I have a question about [this chapter](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-453-quantum-optical-communication-fall-2016/readings-and-lecture-slides/MIT6_453F16_Lect12_Notes.pdf), concerning the linear attenuators and amplifiers.

Specifically, the chapter mentions that they are not going to get $\rho_{out}$, but I am interested in this.

More specifically, I am curious about the number of photons detected from the output $<n|\rho_{out}|n>$, which I know will be a function of the arbitrary input state $\rho_{in}$.

I am at the point where I have the antinormal characteristic function $\chi_{out}(\eta, \eta^*)=\chi_{in}(\eta\sqrt{G},\eta^*\sqrt{G})$ for an arbitrary gain $G>1$. How do I proceed from here to get $<n|\rho_{out}|n>$? Do I just take the operator-valued inverse Fourier transform, as suggested earlier in the course? If so, I **don't know how to do this**, so if someone could provide some help in this calculation for a **non-coherent** state I would appreciate it.

Cheers, W